# New Flex Session for every AMF call in blazeDS

Tags: session, blazeds, logout

i'm trying to login and logout users within the tomcat/blazeDS environment. I wrote a custom Java Login Proxy to handle the login which works. As i tried to logout user i.e. invalidate Sessions i realized that the Flash Application gets a new Session Id (new Session) for every call of the AMF channel. What happens is that if i try to invalidate a session its useless because the next call will be new and valid with the same user credentials again.

How can i logout a user from a Flex Application / Tomcat context then? I cant't find good examples without custom Authentication.

Thanks

Andreas

Comment: No i just created the classes myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to pass the session id from Flex to the Java backend and have the backend invalidate the session to log out the user.